# What cello technique used in titles of "The Night Of"

Tags: technique, sound, cello

At the beginning of the title sequence of "The Night Of" the double bass is clearly plucked, but I'm not entirely sure about the higher cello part? Is it simply a (very) dry staccato? There's just so much - I don't know how to describe it - maybe texture (?), that I'm wondering if it's simply bowed?

Edit: just realised the bass is two double basses: one bowed, one plucked.

Edit: took an attempt to transcribe the music: https://musescore.com/user/24361621/scores/4810734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bow is kind of dropped onto the string, and immediately removed, so it bounces.

Called spiccato, or brush stroke.

Comment: Thanks! So the pizzicato-ish sound underneath is part of the spiccato? Or do you think there's separate strings doing pizzicato as well?